# Check if two closed integer intervals overlap or are neighbours

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two closed integer intervals $[a, b]$ and $[c, d]$. Note that it is possible that $b<a$ (resp., $d<c$), in that case the interval also represents the integers between $a$ and $b$ (resp., $d$ and $c$).

I know that if $$min(max(a,b),max(c,d)) \ge max(min(a,b),min(c,d))$$ then the two intervals overlap.

Now, I would like to introduce the notion of "neighbour": For two integer intervals that do **not** overlap, if $$[min(a, b, c, d), max(a, b, c, d)]=[a,b] \cup [c, d]$$ then we say they are "neighbours". For example, $[1,5]$ and $[6, 9]$ are neighbours.

One way to check if the two intervals are neighbours is:

$$min(max(a,b),max(c,d)) < max(min(a,b),min(c,d)) \wedge\\ (max(a, b) + 1 = min(c, d) \vee max(c, d) + 1 = min(a, b))$$

Therefore, if I want to check if the two intervals overlap or are neighbours, I need a long condition:$$min(max(a,b),max(c,d)) \ge max(min(a,b),min(c,d)) \vee \\ \qquad (min(max(a,b),max(c,d)) < max(min(a,b),min(c,d)) \wedge\\ \qquad (max(a, b) + 1 = min(c, d) \vee max(c, d) + 1 = min(a, b)))$$ which can be reduced to$$min(max(a,b),max(c,d)) < max(min(a,b),min(c,d)) \\\Longrightarrow max(a, b) + 1 = min(c, d) \vee max(c, d) + 1 = min(a, b)$$

However, I still find it complicated. Does anyone know if there is an esay way to check that?